# zabbix-agent active config: ZBX_TCP_READ() failed

Tags: zabbix

I'm using `Zabbix 2.2.6` for both server and clients and trying to configure `zabbix-agent` works only for active mode. Basically I set on `/etc/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.conf`

```
ServerActive=zabbix_server_ip
StartAgents=0
```

I clone 2 templetes in zabbix server web GUI `Template App Zabbix Agent Active` and change all item type to `Zabbix agent active` mode. Then add the client and link to that template.

I also open firewall on Zabbix server port `10050` and `10051` for client. On client I can `telnet` and check that connection is okay for those 2 ports. But I still got this error:

```
active check configuration update from [zabbix_server_ip:10051] started to fail (ZBX_TCP_READ() failed: [104] Connection reset by peer)
```

On passive mode everything work fine except sometimes it returns the anyoing error:

```
Zabbix agent on MY_CLIENT_NODE is unreachable for 5 minutes
```

I think switch to `active` mode can solve this problem since I update the server to latest version of 2.2.x.

Please give me suggest about this case.